# How do you find a mongodb record that is two level deep

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb schema which looks like this. How do you search such a document to `find` the record that matches `Name == Brad`

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57f580efe2ab6485147d0f71"),
"0" : {
    "Name" : "Brad",
    "Age" : 42
},
"1" : {
    "Name" : "Paul",
    "Age" : 32
}
```

}

The schema is handed over to me by the library I use from a `swift` program to save a `JSON` string. The library is [Perfect MongoDB](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-MongoDB).

Comment: Can you change your documents to have an array of Name/Age objects?

Comment: Will documents only contain subdocuments named "0" and "1", or can there be a "2", "3", etc. ?

Comment: Yes, the number progresses as many array in my json.  I think it is a problem with my mongodb library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with pure mongo, I suggest you change the schema.
But, it is possible using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```
db.test.find({
    $where: function() {
        for (var prop in this) {
            if (this[prop]["Name"] == "Brad") {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: How about this, `{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57f6ab3ce2ab6411d53fb831"),
 "users" : [
  {
   "Name" : "Ranjith",
   "Age" : 42
  },
  {
   "Name" : "Paul",
   "Age" : 32
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: @rptony yes, a `users` array make more sense. you will be able to find the user with regular `find` query or filter the array with `$filter` in `aggregation`. You will find easy answers for this problem anywhere :)